# Why do these geometric assumptions imply these statements about relative homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology

I'm reading the paper [Coverage in sensor networks via persistent homology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/persistent.pdf).

As in the paper, let $\mathcal{D}$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbf{R}^d$. We make the following assumptions:

> **A5** The restricted domain $\mathcal{D} - N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D})$ is connected, where $$N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D}) = \{x \in \mathcal{D} : \|x - \mathcal{D}\| \leq \hat{r}\}, \text{ where } \hat{r} = r_f + r_s/\sqrt{2}.$$
>   **A6** The fence detection hypersurface $\Sigma = \{x \in \mathcal{D}: \|x-\partial \mathcal{D}\| = r_f\}
> $ has internal injectivity radius at least $r_s/\sqrt{2}$ and external injectivity radius at least $r_s$.

Here, $r_f$ and $r_s$ are real numbers.

In section 3.1 on page 8 they say:

> With assumptions **A5** and **A6**, the top dimensional relative homology $H_d(\mathcal{D}, N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D}))$ has rank one. Furthermore, $H_d(\mathcal{U} \cup N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D}), N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D}))$ is nonzero if and only if $\mathcal{U}$ contains $\mathcal{D} - N_{\hat{r}}(\partial \mathcal{D})$.

(By the way, $\mathcal{U}$ is a union of open balls centered at points in $\mathcal{D}$.)

Why do these things hold?

*Edit*. More detail about the assumptions:

> Assumption **A5** is needed to prevent the domain from being too 'pinched'.
>
> (...)
>
> Assumption **A6** means that the outermost boundary cannot exhibit large-scale 'wrinkling'.
>
> (...)
>
> Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of points in $\mathbf{R}^d$ within distance $r_s\sqrt{(d-1)/2d}$ of $\Sigma$ on the interior side (i.e. the side of $\Sigma$ corresponding to the interior of $\mathcal{D}$), and within distance $r_s$ of $\Sigma$ on the exterior side.
>
> (...)
>
> From **A6**, we know that $\mathcal{S}$ is a disjoint collection of thickened $(d-1)$-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbf{R}^d$ each of thickness at most $$\Delta = r_s\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{d-1}{2d}}\right).$$
>
> (...)
>
> *Remark* 4.5. The precise statement of **A6** in terms of injectivity radii requires the curve to be smooth. From the proof of theorem 3.4, it is clear that the crucial condition is to have the shell $\mathcal{S}$ represent annular domains of thickness bounded by $\frac{3}{2}r_s$. In practice, having $\partial\mathcal{D}$ piecewise-linear is admissible: even though the injectivity radii degenerate to zero, the set $\mathcal{S}$ is still an annular region(s) of width bounded by some larger length, depending on the sharpness of the curves. For a piecewise-linear $\partial\mathcal{D}$, an increase in $r_w$ based on the angle of the sharpest corner in the outermost boundary component makes the criterion rigorous.

This may help clarify the meaning of **A6**, though most of this (everything except the first two statements) comes after the part that I'm asking about.

Comment: What are the internal and external injectivity radii? I have my guesses, but they might not (and, probably, do not) agree with the definitions you are using. You also need to add more assumptions on the domain $D$, say, contractibility, otherwise, I am pretty sure the statements will fail.

Comment: There aren't any more assumptions on the domain $\mathcal{D}$ in the paper as far as I can see. They don't define the injectivity radii, but I've added some more detail to the question that may help.

Comment: In your edit, you still did not define what $r_f$ and $r_s$ are. Without this definition, your question is meaningless as homology depends on these radii. If $r_f$ and $r_s$ are not defined in the paper you are reading, you should look at other papers by its  authors and see if they have a precise definition there. If they do not, write to the authors.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Assumption A5, I will make another one, namely, that the complement $D\setminus N_{r}(\partial D)$ is nonempty (without this assumption the claim is clearly false). Here and below I set $r=\hat{r}$.

I will also assume that the boundary of $N_r(\partial D)$ is a topological submanifold in $R^d$, in order to simplify the calculation (this assumption can be avoided). Then, by excision:
$$
H_*(D, N_r(\partial D))\cong H_*(D_r, \partial D_r),
$$
where $D_r$ is the complement in $D$ of the interior of $N_r(\partial D)$. Thus, $D_r$ is a $d$-dimensional compact connected manifold with nonempty boundary. By the Lefschetz-Poincare duality:
$$
H_d(D_r, \partial D_r)\cong H^0(D_r)\cong {\mathbb Z}, 
$$
by the connectivity assumption. This answers the first question.

Consider now, some open subset $U\subset D$ and $U_r:= U\cap D_r, V_r:= U_r\cap \partial D_r$. Again, by Lefschetz-Poincare duality:
$$
H_d(U_r, V_r)\cong H^0_c(U_r). 
$$
The latter is zero precisely when $U_r$ has only noncompact components, i.e.,  $U$ does not contain $D_r$.